# How to use sessions in Locomotive.js

Tags: node.js, express, session-variables, connect, locomotivejs

I am giving a look at the node.js web framework [Locomotive](http://locomotivejs.org/). Since it is built on top of [Express](http://expressjs.com/), I suppose Connect middleware should be easily accessible, but I can't find out how.

I added 2 lines to `config/environments/all.js`:

```
this.use(express.cookieParser());
this.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat'}));
```

Where is the session object now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out by myself. It was quite easy:

```
var express = require('express');
var sess = express.session;
```

Comment: the session is actually part of the incoming request objects when you handle things like express routes.